# How to hide node title for specific content type using template file

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to remove a node title on a specific content type (Core Article) using its template file.

I don't want to use preprocess_node() hook that it's pretty straight forward but not of my liking due to I want to organize all my edited templates in my custom template folder.

What I did is this:
I copied the node.tpl.php to my template folder under the folder "templates". I renamed that file to node--article.tpl.php. I edited the template file removing all the header section (which includes the title render function). Cleared the caches but the title is still there.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the code in my node--article.tpl.php

```
<article id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php  print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php  print $attributes; ?>>
   <?php
      // Hide comments, tags, and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      hide($content['field_tags']);
      print render($content);
      ?>  
      <?php
     if (!empty($content['field_tags']) || !empty($content['links'])):
      ?>  
   <footer>
      <?php
         print render($content['field_tags']);
         ?>
      <?php
         print render($content['links']);
         ?>  
   </footer>
   <?php
      endif;
    ?>  
    <?php
      print render($content['comments']);
    ?>
```

PS: Sorry for the code styling but I guess html5 tags are breaking the lines in stack exchange editor.

Comment: Maybe the template is not being used, are you sure that your tpl in your theme is being used?

Comment: please share the code of your template file,so we can debug it

Comment: @Gianni Di Falco How do I make sure of that?

Comment: Break the file and empty cache xD i mean, if you look at bartik's node.tpl.php the $title variable is there so deleting it should not be printed, if still is printed so looks like your theme node--article.tpl.php file is not used. The file is named correctly? it is under the template folder of the active theme?

Comment: @vishal shah I edited the post and added the coding.

Comment: @Gianni Di Falco I removed the title rendering section from both bartik and Bootstrap (I am using a bootstrap subtheme). The title is still there. Is there any other way to see which template is used?

Comment: @pierostz ok.Can you confirm that bootstrap subtheme is enabled for front end from appearance section of admin panel.Also,try to clear the cache again and then check

Comment: Are you possibly printing the node as a page (i.e. page node/123)?

Comment: @lauriii yes I am. I guess zhilevan answer is the correct approach but still...not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you render article as full page then  $title rendered in `page.tpl.php`

you just need override your content type page template, I mean duplicate `page.tpl.php` ( if you use bootsrap sub theme go to  `boostrap` theme boostrap\template\system\page.tpl.php`  file to your subtheme template forlder and rename it to page--article.tpl.php and remove title form it.

I mean remove these lines from it

```
  <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    <h1 class="page-header"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

**dont forget clear the cache**

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. Title is rendered in node.tpl.php if node is not being rendered as a page.

Comment: @lauriii if node render as full page page title getting rendered.

Comment: @zhilevan Did exactly as you described. Copied the page.tpl.php and renamed to page--article.tpl.php and put it in my sub theme's folders. Removed the title rendering lines. Still showing.

Comment: @pierostz So go to debuing phase, put some "die" in your code to be sure which file loaded ( put <?php die('in article page'); ?>  and put <?php die('in node article');?>  to be sure is your template files correctly.

Comment: I am trying a more useful approach at this question. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212815/unable-to-enable-theme-debugging
Do you have any input on that?

Comment: @pierostz that question is about drupal 8 and this one is about 7,

Comment: @zhilevan what do you mean? I asked the question and is about 7. Am I wrong?

Comment: @pierostz no, another link you mentioned in previous comment is about drupal 8, anyway you can simple find your problem, check which file loaded and remove title from it